# Preferences for simplifying

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I often (always?) find that Mathematica prefers to express $(a-1)^2$ as $(-1+a)^2$, thus "wasting" a character. Moreover, for me, the expression $(a-1)^2$ is more attractive since it doesn't have the dangling negative sign. While other people will disagree, my question is the following:

Can I set my preferences for how Mathematica should treat specific situations of this kind?

Comment: `(a - 1)^2 // TraditionalForm`

Comment: This is not really about simplification but canonicalization of sums.  `Plus` has the `Orderless` attribute, which means that its terms are sorted.  Such automatic sorting brings e.g. `a+b` and `b+a` to the same form (the sorted `a+b`) which makes it possible to verify if they are identical.

Comment: `TraditionalForm` won't change the order in which terms are stored internally, but it will change the way a sum is displayed. It affects presentation, but not computation or internal representation. I agree with Bob that it's the best solution to your problem.

Comment: also `PolynomialForm[(a - 1)^2, TraditionalOrder -> True]`